# Jackson Returns empty object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm new to Jackson. I've tried to parse Json string to an object but jackson returns an object with all null values. Here is code of my parser:

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 FullTextRetrievalResponse object =  
 mapper.readValue(response.getBody().getObject().toString(), 
 FullTextRetrievalResponse.class);
```

Here is my FullTextRetrievalResponse class:

```
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
 @JsonPropertyOrder({
"coredata",
"scopus-id",
"scopus-eid",
"link",
"originalText"
})

public class FullTextRetrievalResponse {

@JsonProperty("coredata")
private Coredata coredata;
@JsonProperty("scopus-id")
private String scopusId;
@JsonProperty("scopus-eid")
private String scopusEid;
@JsonProperty("link")
private Link_ link;
@JsonProperty("originalText")
private OriginalText originalText;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("coredata")
public Coredata getCoredata() {
    return coredata;
}

@JsonProperty("coredata")
public void setCoredata(Coredata coredata) {
    this.coredata = coredata;
}

@JsonProperty("scopus-id")
public String getScopusId() {
    return scopusId;
}

@JsonProperty("scopus-id")
public void setScopusId(String scopusId) {
    this.scopusId = scopusId;
}

@JsonProperty("scopus-eid")
public String getScopusEid() {
    return scopusEid;
}

@JsonProperty("scopus-eid")
public void setScopusEid(String scopusEid) {
    this.scopusEid = scopusEid;
}

@JsonProperty("link")
public Link_ getLink() {
    return link;
}

@JsonProperty("link")
public void setLink(Link_ link) {
    this.link = link;
}

@JsonProperty("originalText")
public OriginalText getOriginalText() {
    return originalText;
}

@JsonProperty("originalText")
public void setOriginalText(OriginalText originalText) {
    this.originalText = originalText;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

and here is part of JSON:

```
{
"full-text-retrieval-response": {
    "coredata": {
        "prism:url": "http://api.elsevier.com/content/article/pii/S1751157716302140",
        "dc:identifier": "doi:10.1016/j.joi.2016.11.002",
        "eid": "1-s2.0-S1751157716302140",
        "prism:doi": "10.1016/j.joi.2016.11.002",
        "pii": "S1751-1577(16)30214-0",
        "dc:title": "The specific shapes of gender imbalance in scientific authorships: A network approach ",
        "prism:publicationName": "Journal of Informetrics",
        "prism:aggregationType": "Journal",
        "prism:issn": "17511577",
        "prism:coverDate": "2017-02-28",
        "prism:coverDisplayDate": "February 2017",
        "openaccess": "0",
        "openaccessArticle": false,
        "openaccessType": null,
        "openArchiveArticle": false,
        "openaccessSponsorName": null,
        "openaccessSponsorType": null,
        "openaccessUserLicense": null,
        "link": [
            {
                "@rel": "self",
                "@href": "http://api.elsevier.com/content/article/pii/S1751157716302140",
                "@_fa": "true"
            },
            {
                "@rel": "scidir",
                "@href": "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1751157716302140",
                "@_fa": "true"
            }
        ]
    }
}
  }
```

Comment: Where's the problem?

Comment: `readValue` throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException and IOException - show what your code does about this

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that in your json object you have the field `full-text-retrieval-response` wrapping all your object, but in your java classes, the `FullTextRetrievalResponse` is the root.

I think you have 3 options

1. Change the json structure (supposing you can do that), removing the `full-text-retrieval-response` label (https://pastebin.com/MtxXSeDW)
2. Create a new class having an instance of `FullTextRetrievalResponse` as a json property:

   ```
   public class FullTextRetrievalResponseWrapper {
      @JsonProperty("full-text-retrieval-response")
      private FullTextRetrievalResponse fullTextRetrievalResponse;
      //setters and getters 
   }
   ```

   And then make the serialization using this new class: `mapper.readValue(response.getBody().getObject().toString(), 
   FullTextRetrievalResponseWrapper .class);`
3. Create a custon json deserializer (http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) to convert yourself the json object to your class.

   Just another quick tip: if you are defining a field as a json property (`@JsonProperty`), you do not need to define the `@JsonSetter`, `@JsonGetter` or even the `@JsonProperty` in the setters and getters.